# Speed of UIImage(data: ) compare reading it from dictionary

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage, uicollectionview

I am thinking how to read / open an image fast as possible. The concept I imagined is to use a 'memory cache', load images to a generic dictionary:

```
public var images = [String: UIImage]()
```

and read it in a tableView from there when it is needed.

Do you think it is somewhat faster then load it directly? iOS is so much faster, and optimized nowadays. How 'slow' is operation like:

```
let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: path)
let image = UIImage(data: data)
```

My other thought is to put  this two line on the the background tread, and when it is done call the assign image to imageView operation on main thread, do you think it is overkill?

Usually I am using image loading operation in heavy used delegate methods like: `cellForItemAtIndexPath`.

Comment: You should never store the `UIImage` or `NSData` in the `Dictionary`, it increases the memory like anything. The approach is to use the `NSCache` to store the images.

Comment: The background thread idea is not overkill and should be done if you want your apps experience to be as smooth as possible. use a placeholder image while it is loading then swap it out once its completed. (unless the images are quite small, then it could just look like flickering if it loads really fast, up to you what looks best)

Comment: @New16 why? Dictionary and `NSCache` are similar animals, `NSDictionary` would be better, or only `NSCache`? Is it any 'official proof' of it or this is only your experience?

Comment: @János do you consider memory related issues. The `NSCache` has an an advantage if you are running out of memory it will be purged first. The same thing you can't achieve with the `NSDictionary`. You can go through this http://nshipster.com/nscache/. Also I agree with the @Fonix answer.